# javascript access json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i´ve got a question regarding accessing json objects/arras via javascript:
so i have this array (got it from the backend):

```
let resp = [
    {
        "4-13-2022": {
            "8:28:53 PM": {
                "title": "one",
                "topic": "two",
                "details": "tree",
                "type": "thought"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and i want to access the "title" value.

**Things i tried:**

- resp[0][0].title
- resp[0][0][0]
- resp[0][0][0].title
- resp[0].title

any of my attempts returned a `undefined` error/response
any advice?

**EDIT:**
here is the full snippet:

```
<script>
        const getid = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
        let overview = "";
        let resp = [];
        let temp = [
            {
                "8:28:53 PM": {
                    title: "one",
                    topic: "two",
                    details: "tree",
                    type: "thought",
                },
            },
        ];
        fetch("http://localhost:1200/rData/overview", { credentials: "include" })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                resp = res;
                for (let li in res) {
                    overview += `<li><details><summary>${Object.keys(res[li])}</summary>${temp[0].title}</details></li>`;
                }
                getid("dataList").innerHTML = overview;
                console.log(overview);
                console.log(temp[0]);
            })
            .then((getid("dataList").innerHTML = overview))
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
</script>
```

Comment: show more code. did you parse the object or?

Comment: oh thanks, i forgot to parse it, oh men

Comment: Please be aware that the data is JavaScript and not JSON

Comment: Inspect each "layer" of your array - you seem to be attempting to access nested arrays, but there is only one array here; the rest are objects or strings.

Comment: my guess is that you have a malformed array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

According to your data structure you can access title as follows

```
resp[0]["4-13-2022"]["8:28:53 PM"].title
```

or you can use Object.values to get the first Property

```
Object.values((Object.values(resp[0])[0]))[0].title
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON.

```
JSON.parse(resp)
```

and then you can access it as a regular javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(resp)` to find the first key in resp. Then you can use `Object.keys` again on the inner object.

```
const dateKey = Object.keys(resp)[0];
const inner = resp[dateKey];
const timeKey = Object.keys(inner)[0];
const title = inner[timeKey].title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad data.

This:

```
let temp = [   { "8:28:53 PM": {
                     title: "one",
                     topic: "two",
                     details: "tree",
                     type: "thought",
                     },
               },
            ];
```

Should look more like this:

```
let temp = [   { timestamp: "8:28:53 PM",
                 data: {
                     title: "one",
                     topic: "two",
                     details: "tree",
                     type: "thought",
                     },
               },
            ];

console.log(temp[0].data.title);
```

or even this:

```
let temp = [   { timestamp: "8:28:53 PM",
                 title: "one",
                 topic: "two",
                 details: "tree",
                 type: "thought"
               },
            ];

console.log(temp[0].title);
```

Comment: thank you, adopted your datastruckture-idea

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var title=resp[0]["4-13-2022"]["8:28:53 PM"].title; // one
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring as follows:

```js
const resp = [ { "4-13-2022": { "8:28:53 PM": { "title": "one", "topic": "two", "details": "tree", "type": "thought" } } } ];

const [{"4-13-2022":{"8:28:53 PM":{title}}}] = resp;
//To get all the other properties, just list them with title:
//const [{"4-13-2022":{"8:28:53 PM":{title,topic,details,type}}}] = resp;

console.log( title );
```

If you have more than one element in the `resp` array, it's difficult to iterate through the items(elements) and get the desired properties, but it can be done.

```js
const resp = [ { "4-13-2022": { "8:28:53 PM": { "title": "one", "topic": "two", "details": "tree", "type": "thought" } } },{ "4-13-2022": { "8:32:20 PM": { "title": "two", "topic": "five", "details": "six", "type": "watch out" } } },{ "4-14-2022": { "8:28:53 PM": { "title": "thirty", "topic": "tomorrow", "details": "never", "type": "comes" } } } ];

for(const [[date,[[time,{title,topic,details,type}]]]] of 
        resp.map(r => Object.entries(r).map(([d,v]) => 
            [d,Object.entries(v)])) ) {
    console.log( date,time,title,topic,details,type );
    //do something ....
}
```

But as you can see this is quite involved. If you have control of the backend I would suggest changing the structure of your data to something like or something simpler:

```
let resp = [
{
    "date": "4-13-2022",
    "time": "8:28:53 PM",
    "title": "one",
    "topic": "two",
    "details": "tree",
    "type": "thought"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let resp = [
    {
        "4-13-2022": {
            "8:28:53 PM": {
                "title": "one",
                "topic": "two",
                "details": "tree",
                "type": "thought"
            }
        }
    }
]
var title=resp[0]["4-13-2022"]["8:28:53 PM"].title; 
console.log("title =",title);
```